# PUT request with curl in PHP conversion

Tags: php, json, api, curl

I have to make a PUT request in PHP, in the documentation of the API I have the example:

```
 curl --request PUT \
      --url 'http://url
      --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
      --header 'TOKENMM: {{TOKEN}}' \
      --data '[
    {
    "item1": 123,
    "item2": 231,
    "item3": 321
    },
  {
    "item1": 456,
    "item2": 465,
    "item3": 654
  }
]'
```

How can I do that request using PHP's curl? I tried some answers to similar questions but with no success.

Here is what I have so far:

```
private function getInfoAPI($data_json){

        print_r($data_json);
        $url = 'url';
        $authorization = "TOKENMM: token";

    $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,  ['Content-Type: application/json', $authorization]);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data_json);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $response  = curl_exec($ch);
        echo curl_error($ch);
        var_dump( curl_getinfo ( $ch ) );
        curl_close($ch);

        return $response;
    }
```

Comment: whats the result of the PHP invocation?

Comment: nothing returned. When I used var_dump on $response it returns me an empty string.

Comment: You might want to throw in a `echo curl_error($ch);` and a `var_dump( curl_getinfo ( $ch ) );`

Comment: Both are not returning anything. Am I missing something in my function?

Comment: @ErickSkrobot if `curl_getinfo()` isn't returning anything I don't think your `getInfoAPI($data_json)` function is getting called at all. The getinfo call tells about all the connection information. Make sure you are putting it before the `curl_close()`

Comment: I did. To make sure inside the function I'm also printing my $data_json and that is printing with no problem. I'm updating my function im my question.

Comment: show us the output of running that function, all the various outputs.

Comment: I solved by using Postman to generate the code, I'll post the code that worked for me. Thank you guys for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by building the request on Postman and generating the code in PHP there. The code that worked for me is:

```
private function getInfoAPI($data_json){

        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($curl, [CURLOPT_URL => "url",
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "PUT",
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data_json,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
        "Cache-Control: no-cache",
        "Content-Type: application/json",
        "TOKEN: SAMPLE_TOKEN"],]);

        $response = curl_exec($curl);    
        curl_close($curl);

        return $response;
    }
```